# Does there exist a topological transitive dynamical system that diverges to infinity for all initial conditions?

Tags: dynamical-systems

[Topological transitivity](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Topological_transitivity) is a property of dynamical systems.

My question is: Does there exist a topological transitive dynamical system in the usual plane or the usual space that diverges to infinity for all initial conditions. This means that the image of any point by the successive compositions of the map goes to infinity.

Comment: wut does 'diverges to infinity' mean

Comment: @mathworker21: This means that the image of any point by the successive compositions of the map goes to infinity.

Comment: what is 'infinity' for an arbitrary metric space

Comment: @mathworker21: The same as the case of the real line.

Comment: what are you talking about? do you know what a metric space is? if not, you shouldn't be doing topological dynamics

Comment: @mathworker21: For example in the usual plane or the usual space. See the edited question.

Comment: @mathworker21: So, what is the correct sentence

Comment: if you want to talk about $\mathbb{R}^n$, just say so. also, the answer in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is obviously "no", by the definition of topological transitivity. if a point goes off to infinity, then it can't visit every open set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For otherwise, by definition, there is some $x_0$ s.t. $\{x_0,T(x_0),T^2(x_0),\dots\}$ is dense in $X$, but this easily contradicts $T^n(x_0) \to \infty$.